# HTML colorbox Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

Hi i have a question i am using colorbox javascript from here [ColorBOx](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/) . I am trying to use

```
<a class="callbacks cboxElement" href="../content/marylou.jpg" title="Marylou on Cumberland Island">Example with alerts</a>
```

which was provided from the example given. i would like to know how am i suppose to call this method from javascript instead of click on the link and open . Thanks

this is what i would do with a button

Answer

```
 $.colorbox({
                    onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                    onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                    onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                    onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                    onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
                });
```

Comment: It tells you on this page http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: haxtbh thanks for the link i may have miss it :)